# how to write plist array of dictionary objects..dynamically and populating the tableview

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

m working with `plist` and i am new to it..
I want to save two type of values,these two are labels,i.e

`label1`
`label2`

so for that i tried to write the code but was able to save   only for one
label i.e `label1`..in a plist and then populate it into the table so i got one value on
`cell.textlabel.text = label1.text`

but i need this also..

`cell.detailedlabel.text = label2.text`

so below is my code.. to save `label1.text`

```
-(IBAction) myBrand:(id) sender
{
     NSLog(@"mylist  Clicked");    
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory,      NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];    

    NSString *plistPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];


    [array addObjectsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]];
    [array addObject:searchLabel.text];

    [array writeToFile:plistPath atomically: TRUE];    
}
```

now if i want o save one more label..in the array and populate it on cells detailedlabel..how shall i proceed..please help me out..

Hi friends..I want o have something like this....

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    // get paths from root direcory

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    // get documents path



     NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];    // get the path to our Data/plist file
        NSString *plistPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

        //This copies objects of plist to array if there is one
        [array addObjectsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]];
        //[array addObject:entity];
        [array insertObject:entity atIndex:0];
       [array insertObject:category atIndex:0];

        NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: entity, category, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Entity", @"Category", nil]];
```

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: i didn't understood your problem.. you want to write the plist file or populate the tableview??

Comment: Hi shrey..i want to do both....

Comment: Try to use this:

myArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:myTempArray];
[myArray addObject:myObject];

I am not sure about this but hope this would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go through the portion of the code below which will solve your problem of storing both label values in plist...

```
NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary* newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[newDict setValue:label1.text forKey:labell];    //forKey identify the name of the array element in dictionary for plist
[newDict setValue:label2.text forKey:label2];

[data addObject:newDrink];
[newDict release];
```